# Airflow keep creating file from my function even if my dag is closed

Tags: python-3.x, function, airflow

I tried to create a workflow that will create a htmlfile first, and read it to do something:

A function that will create a file:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from urllib.request import Request

filename = datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%Y-%H:%M:%S")
def createfile():
        my_url = myurl 
        headers = headers
        reqq = Request(url = my_url, headers = headers)
        uclient = uReq(reqq)
        page_html = uclient.read()
        uclient.close()

        with open(filename, 'w' ) as f:
            f.write(page_html.decode('utf-8'))
            f.close()
        #dosomething
        page_soup = soup(open(filename), "html.parser")
        #do
```

And I use `PythonOperator` to call it in a dag file :

```
py_task1 = PythonOperator(task_id='Info',
                      python_callable=  createfile,
                      dag=dag)
```

How to avoid airflow from keep creating file from my function?

Comment: Hi there, could you try to be more specific in describing your problem, e.g. your `createfile` function creates a file every time the airflow task is executed, what are you trying to avoid here and could you add the `IOError` that you are talking about?

Comment: My airflow will create a text file of `datetime.now()`  when I upstream my dag, even if I close the dag or I didn't run it, I just run `airflow webserver` and `airflow scheduler` in command line and it will keep creating files, what should I do to avoid that?

Comment: You can see that the dag is paused in the web UI? What is the `schedule_interval` of the dag, does it correlate to the files that are created? Are the files also created if you only run the webserver without the scheduler?

Comment: Yeah the dag is definitely paused in UI, my schedule_interveal is timedelta(hours=1) and even if I stop airflow webserver the file keep creating(I didn't stop scheduler), is that scheduler's issue?

Comment: I need to stop both to aviod my dag from creating files(if I start scheduler or webserver it will start creating, the dag is paused and no error is raised)

Comment: If you only start the webserver and files are created, that probably means that the file is created when airflow parses your python files, so you should probably double check that you don't call the create function outside of an operator